# Login page - simple, secure way to implement authentication against active directory?

Tags: authentication, web, iis

I'm creating a small web app running on IIS and I need to implement a secure way to handle login authentication against active directory.

Currently, I have it set up with Windows authentication, so when users first go to the website it shows the login prompt from the browser, they login using their AD credentials, and then it allows them into the site.

However, I want to have an actual login page and have these credentials validated against AD instead of Windows Authentication. I've been researching for hours about LDAP but I can't seem to find good documentation/videos on how to set it up to communicate with AD. I've thought about using 3rd party services like Okta but I don't think I need to.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff650308(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN At least Microsoft has one for you. "Simple" and "secure" are subjective.

Comment: What is the Tech Stack you are using? i.e. `ASP.NET`?

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to use active directory authentication in IIS, then you can only use windows authentication, unless you use some non-IIS authentication methods.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.